Issues with the Graph API M365 group posts endpoint
I've been looking at the graph api documentation related to M365 group posts. I wanted to create one using app permissions. The doc article says you can use the reply endpoint on a given post using app permissions which I tried and does not work. I always get a ErrorAccessDenied. I double checked and Group.ReadWrite.All is consented in app permissiong on my app, even checked the JWT in the auth header and it does contain that permission.
Here is my payload
{"Post":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.post","body":{"content":"Hello World!","contentType":"text"},"from":{"emailAddress":{"address":"adelev@2hpq4n.onmicrosoft.com"}}}}

I then tried in delegated permission with the same payload I also ensured the Group.ReadWrite.All permission is consented in delegated permission. From the doc article it seems to be possible to set someone else for the from property specifically used in the delegated access scenario :

I tried with the same payload as above and the from property, once the post is created, always ends up to be the user I did the request with, so I do not think that works either.
Am I doing something wrong here?
